# Move files with spaces in the name

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to move some files in python, but they have spaces in the name. Is  there any way to specifically tell python to treat a string as a file name?

```
listing = os.listdir(self.Parent.userTempFolderPath)
for infile in listing:
    if infile.find("Thumbs.db") == -1 and infile.find("DS") == -1:

        fileMover.moveFile(infile, self.Parent.userTempFolderPath, self.Parent.currentProjectObject.Watchfolder, True)
```

After I get the file from the listing, I run `os.path.exists` on it to see if it exists, and it never exists! Can somebody give me a hint here?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Error: File or directory does not exist" BUT they do exist as confirmed by os.listdir](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163846/error-file-or-directory-does-not-exist-but-they-do-exist-as-confirmed-by-os-l)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spaces in the filenames are not the problem; `os.listdir` returns filenames, not full paths.

You'll need to add them to your filenames to test them; [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) will do this for you with the correct directory separator for your platform:

```
listing = os.listdir(self.Parent.userTempFolderPath)
for infile in listing:
    if 'Thumbs.db' not in infile and 'DS' not in infile:
        path = os.path.join(self.Parent.userTempFolderPath, infile)

        fileMover.moveFile(path, self.Parent.userTempFolderPath, self.Parent.currentProjectObject.Watchfolder, True)
```

Note that I also simplified your filename tests; instead of using `.find(..) == -1` I use the `not in` operator.

Comment: ...and for the love of everything holy, don't use find() for substring existence.  Use `in` or `not in` in this case.

Comment: or `os.chdir(self.Parent.userTempFolderPath)` before using the relative path.

Comment: @KurzedMetal: which has other suprising effects if you run external commands from your script. Better stick with absolute paths.

Comment: There's nothing surprising about changing directories, maybe it is if you use relative paths when you shouldn't or when you didn't manually set your current directory. The important question is... do you really run external commands without double checking you are in the correct directory? i don't.

Comment: @KurzedMetal: Explicit is better than implicit; absolute paths remove the need for a context.